# Axios: How to send Params as Query String

Tags: httprequest, axios, put, http-request-parameters

This is the base of my code

```
    const params = {
            contractId: data.contractId,
            notificationEmail: data.notificationEmail,
            userNumber: data.userNumber
    }

    axios.put(update_user_url, params, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}`
            }
        }).then(blablabla....)
```

However Axios sends the contractId, email and User fields in body, not as a Query string. How do I make it send a query string?

Answer (score 1):

```
axios.put(
   `${base_url}/user`,
     null,
     {
        params: params,
        headers: {
          Authorization: token
        }
     }
);
```

Check the [documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config).

Comment: Isn't there a more elegant way than writing the query string myself?
Can't Axios do it for me?